# Different object access different members

Tags: c#

There is a class lets say calculator which add some values

```
public class Calculator
{
public int Addition(int a, int b)
{....}
public int Addition2(int a, int b, int c)
{....}
public int Addition3(int a, int b,int c, int d)
{....}

}
```

in Main:

```
Calculator calc= new Calculator();
// create object
```

how do I create object or objects so that I can restrict object access to specific functions only.

Ex: obj1 has access to Addition only, obj2 has access to Addition & Addition2 and so on. Means define specific objects access to class functions.

Lets

Comment: You can declare interfaces with function, InterfaceAdditionFirst with Addition1. Then you can make object as InterfaceAdditionFirst calc = new Calculator();

Comment: isn't it actually overwriting the whole code. means doesn't it makes sense to create object and define access at the moment or maybe add some attributes.

Comment: I think interfaces is the best option, I add answer so you can check it. There are other answer which is also good, but in my solution there is something more: inheritance on interfaces also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public interface ICalculator
{
    int Addition(int a, int b);
}
public interface ICalculator1 : ICalculator
{
    int Addition2(int a, int b, int c);
}
public interface ICalculator2 : ICalculator1
{
    int Addition3(int a, int b, int c, int d);
}
public class Calculator : ICalculator2
{
    public int Addition(int a, int b)
    { return 1; }
    public int Addition2(int a, int b, int c)
    { return 1; }
    public int Addition3(int a, int b, int c, int d)
    { return 1; }
}
```

Then in your main function:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //Access to first func
    ICalculator calculator = new Calculator();
    calculator.Addition(1, 1);
    //Access to first & second func
    ICalculator1 calculator1 = new Calculator();
    calculator1.Addition(1, 1);
    calculator1.Addition2(1, 1, 1);
    //Access to first & second & third func
    ICalculator2 calculator2 = new Calculator();
    calculator2.Addition(1, 1);
    calculator2.Addition2(1, 1, 1);
    calculator2.Addition3(1, 1, 1, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) is a powerful tool to publish certain members while others can remain hidden.

```
public interface IAddition
{
    public int Addition(int a, int b)
}

public interface IAddition2
{
    public int Addition2(int a, int b, int c)
}
public interface IAddition3
{
    public int Addition3(int a, int b,int c, int d)
}

public class Calculator : IAddition, IAddition2, IAddition3
{
    public int Addition(int a, int b)
    public int Addition2(int a, int b, int c)
    public int Addition3(int a, int b, int c, int d)           
}

IAddition addition = new Calculator();
IAddition2 addition2 = new Calculator();
IAddition3 addition3 = new Calculator();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Calculator` implement multiple interfaces

```cs
public class Calculator : IAddition1, IAddition2, IAddition3
{
public int Addition(int a, int b)
{....}
public int Addition2(int a, int b, int c)
{....}
public int Addition3(int a, int b, int c, int d)
{....}

}

interface IAddition1 {
  int Addition(int a, int b)
}
interface IAddition2 {
  int Addition(int a, int b, int c)
}
interface IAddition3 {
  int Addition(int a, int b, int c, int d)
}
```

Then you can create it as

```
IAddition2 calc = new Calculator();
```

And it will only have int `Addition2(int a, int b, int c)`